# Regex - first steps

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I wanted to use regular expressions in C# for the very first time. I use them in SQL Server fluently, but there it's very easy compared to what I experienced here...

For starters, I wanted to tackle simple string (taken from another question):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string FullString = "[http: Something] One Two Three[http: AnotherOne] Four[http: BlahBlah] sdksaod,cne 9ofew {}@:P{";
    Regex regex = new Regex(".*[[]http:.*[]]");

    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(FullString))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I was hoping that I will receive matches at `[http: Something]...`,
`[http: AnotherOne]...` and `[http: BlahBlah]...`, but with current attemp, match start at `[http: AnotherOne]...` and ends just before `[http: BlahBlah]`, if I add `.*` at the end of the pattern, match is whole string.

I am curious, why it gives me just one match instead of three expected matches. I am browsing thorugh regular expressions manual and other posts, but can't understand it.

What would be the valid pattern to get those matches? (I don't need in-detail explanation, I think I'll figure out myself what I'll be given).

**All comes down to this** (in case I wasn't clear)

I want to match `[http:...]`, where three dots can be anything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `[[]` is a very SQL Server specific way to escape `[` btw, elsewhere you would use \ to escape special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\[http:.*?])");
```

The `@` is for a literal string (could have used `\\` in the string instead).

The `(` starts a capturing group.

The `\` escapes the following `[` as otherwise `[` would be the start of a character class.

The `?` makes the `*` non-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following pattern: `@"\[http:[^\]]*\]"`. This means "Match a sequence of characters that starts with `[http`, then has a sequence of any length of any character *except* `]`, then ends with `]`".

**Edit:** The non-greedy version of `*` suggested by Andrew Morton is a good (and probably cleaner) alternative to `[^\]]`.

Comment: Also I guess you have looked at this already, but just in case: [The official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions)

Comment: Somehow, I missed that! Thank you!